# Django указывает ошибку там где ее нет

Tags: python, django, backend

Приветсвую!

Возникла проблема с Django, в почти пустом файле modules.py, при запуске вышла ошибка.

**Код с modules.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
```

**Ошибка которая выдается**

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/idrismahmudov/Desktop/web-app/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/idrismahmudov/Desktop/web-app/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/idrismahmudov/Desktop/web-app/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/idrismahmudov/Desktop/web-app/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/idrismahmudov/Desktop/web-app/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/idrismahmudov/Desktop/web-app/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/idrismahmudov/Desktop/web-app/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/Users/idrismahmudov/Desktop/web-app/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 27, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/Users/idrismahmudov/Desktop/web-app/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 50, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules("admin", register_to=site)
  File "/Users/idrismahmudov/Desktop/web-app/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 58, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module("%s.%s" % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/idrismahmudov/Documents/My projects/web-app/solekovsky/main/admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import Post
ImportError: cannot import name 'Post' from 'main.models' (/Users/idrismahmudov/Documents/My projects/web-app/solekovsky/main/models.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

Предпоследняя строка ошибки

```py
    from .models import Post
```

указывает на проблему в том, что вы пытаетесь импортировать модель `Post` из файла `models.py`, а её там нет.

Comment: Да, в этом и заключался вопрос. 
Как это решить?)

Comment: @Idris, добавить модель в файл? не импортировать модель из этого файла? импортировать модель из того файла, где она есть?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, я вас не понял